# Scanner.nextBoolean()'s relevance to this program

Tags: java

I have an assignment where I have to ask a person something and then when they respond it will ask another question.

The person chooses one or the other and depending on what they pick, a different question pops up.

The instructor told us to use Scanner.nextBoolean() after asking the second question (depending on how the user answered the first question).

I jut don't understand how Scanner.nextBoolean() is relevant or how I would use it in this instance. If I made no sense up there here is the question (please don't write any code.. I just want to know how I might use this and if I need to add any extra Scanner info so I don't get the "can't do static reference blah blah blah):

Write a program that first asks the user to enter 1 if they are female or 2 if they are male. Then if they say they are female, ask if they play ice hockey (hint: Scanner.nextBoolean()). If so, output “Awesome!”, otherwise output “You should try it some day.” If they say they are male, ask how many times they ate pizza last week. If it's more than five, tell them they need to eat better, otherwise tell them “OK”.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You ask the if the play ice hockey. The user enters true or false, and nextBoolean allows telling what the user entered.

Comment: Though personally I think it's a bit artificial. A user will usually answer "yes" or "no" and `nextBoolean()` doesn't accept that. It's not natural to answer "true" and "false". But if that's what the teacher wants...

Comment: I agree with you, RealSkeptic.. I thought it was kind of an awkward thing to put.

Comment: JB Nizet.. what do you mean by allows telling what the user entered? So far I have an if statement, if answered 1 then ask the hockey question, but I am just confused what I am supposed to do from there.

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher is mistaken if he/she is asking you to use nextBoolean() to enter 1 or 2.

Instead, I would recommend you use nextInt(). I know you asked for no sample code, but I think it's important that you see an example.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int choice = in.nextInt();
if(choice == 1)
{
    //Your question if the response is 1
}
else if(choice == 2)
{
   //Your question if the response is 2
}
```

If your teacher says you didn't follow instructions by using nextInt(), you can try to use nextBoolean() and show him/her what happens.